# Oracle pl/sql Read the contents of a file from Physical Directory

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

My questions is as follows:
   I am trying to create a script which will execute in sqlplus and what this script will do is that i will have a file in which you can write inside 1 name on every line. So i wanted to use  an Associative Array in which i will read the contents of the file line by line (1 name on every line) and store every name in the array.

My problem is that i cannot use the UTL_FILE package which has a ready GET_LINE procedure to get the name of every line because it has to take as argument a "Logical Directory" of Oracle.
   My issue is that i cannot make changes to the database like to create a new directory or use one of the default directories for the in file. I have to come to a solution in which i will read the contents of the file from a physical location.
   I am kindly asking for some assistance in 2 fields. If you can please help me if you know any other package which can work on a physical location or if know any other way in which maybe i can call sqlplus (sqlplus username/pass @myscript) and give there as an argument the input file or like initialize the array from there.

Thank you in advance.
Any help would be highly appreciated
George

Comment: Are you running SQL*Plus on the server, or on your client computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot make any change to the database and the existing database does not provide you the privileges you need, you're out of luck.

`UTL_FILE` either requires the presence of an Oracle directory object that points to a physical directory on the database server that you have privileges on or that you are using a physical directory that you have been given access to via the deprecated `UTL_FILE_DIR` parameter.  It appears that you are stating that neither of these is a viable option.  If that is the case, you cannot use `UTL_FILE`.

You could also create an external table that would read data from a file.  That would require that you could create the Oracle directory object and the external table.  Again, it sounds like you are saying that is not an option so external tables are out.

You could write a Java (or .Net if you're on Windows) stored procedure that would read from the file.  That would require that you create the procedure and that you grant the owner the necessary file system privileges.  It sounds like you're saying this is also not an option so Java stored procedures are out.

If you move the file to the client machine, you could use SQL*Loader on the client machine to load the data into a table in the database.  That would require that you create a physical table in the database, though, which it sounds like you are saying is not possible.  So SQL*Loader is out.

If you can move the file to the client, you could obviously write a program in whatever language you would like to read the file and build whatever PL/SQL block you'd like.  But that won't work for files stored on the database server barring some sort of very odd permissions grants where your client machine can somehow mount a directory on the server.

So we're back to where we started.  Reading a file from the server's operating system requires privileges to be able to read that file.  You seem to be saying that you do not have and cannot get those privileges.  Therefore, you're saying that you can't do what you want.  Whoever in your organization is asking you to implement this change needs to talk with whoever is preventing you from getting the privileges you need to do your job.  One of them needs to give ground.

Comment: 1 comment below suggests that i can use the DBMS_LOB package. If this one can read from a physical path rather than a directory then the job  can be done without any changes on the database

Comment: @GeorgeGeorgiou - Nope.  You'd need a directory object for `dbms_lob`.  Why would Oracle go to all the trouble of developing systems to control access to files on the server's file system and enforce that in one package (`utl_file`) and then create a back door that violates that system of controls in a different package?  That would be nonsensical.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly the best solution is to use UTL_FILE or external tables. So not being able to change the database is a major problem.  If you don't have the permission to create a directory object and you cannot persuade a privileged user to do so on your behalf, then your question basically becomes

> "How can I circumvent the security restrictions imposed on the database?"

Well, there are two possibilities.

If the DBAs have been careless enough to enable the UTL_FILE_DIR parameter in the init.ora file you may still be able to use UTL_FILE, by passing an absolute file path to FOPEN().

Alternatively, you can write a Java Stored Procedure to interact with files on the OS.  This requires privileges to be granted through the Java security model.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e10588/chten.htm#JJDEV13333).  Again, you will only have this without asking if you have lax DBAs.

Let me make it clear, both these "solutions" are grey hat.  You really should try to get the necessary privileges through the proper channels.  If the DBA team won't create a directory are you can use you need to escalate it to your boss.

Comment: To get privileges on the database or make any changes on it is a serious issue. To ask to make a change on the database you must be 1000% sure that this cannot be done in any other way. 1 idiot way that i worked around it was to define variables in the in file. Like for 5 users i was DEFINE USER1 = asdasd and get the names as variables using the & but this is a very amateur and idiot way to do it. One friend below suggests to use the DBMS_LOB package. I will check that tomorrow and if it works then no need for permissions or changes on the dba. Thank you very much for your concern

Comment: I tried BFIELNAME (see my comment on that post), it won't do it for you.